# What is the behavior of the findOne method in MongoOperations in SpringData?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I am reading SpringData MongoDB configuration for MongoOperations http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#findOne-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-java.lang.Class-

Still do not understand what is the behavior of the findOne method if more than one document satisfies a query:

```
<T> T   findOne(Query query, Class<T> entityClass)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Mongo documentation itself, the `findOne()` method will return the first element encountered, based on the *natural order* of the elements on disk:

> Returns one document that satisfies the specified query criteria. If multiple documents satisfy the query, this method returns the first document according to the natural order which reflects the order of documents on the disk. In capped collections, natural order is the same as insertion order. If no document satisfies the query, the method returns null
>
> http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/